# override onclick behaviour of Push message Android

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification

I'm developing a chat message App.

When clicking on the Push Message I want to be able to influence the behaviour based on the state of the App. Because:

- when the App is out of the phone memory, it should show the login screen
- But when the App is active and opened, and the list of chats is displayed, it should show the push message and when clicking it shouldn't show the login because the user is already logged in.

code:

```
class PushMessageService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage?) {
        // override some method that gets triggered as soon as user clicks on the push message.
    }
}
```

Now it starts the activity defined as MAIN in Androidmanifest:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I can add the code in that Activity but I prefer PushMessageService to handle this. Is this possible?

Comment: yes, use data only message and show custom notification

Comment: You can create a pending intent and define which activity you want to show on a notification click. https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#click

Comment: Also pay attention when server send info in `notification` block `onMessageReceived` will be called only if app in foreground,  and if in `data` block, notifications will be always managed through onMessageReceived.